# X.PagedList.Mvc and PagedList not working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I have a project, that I am working on, and I basically followed the ASP.NET MVC5 tutorial. I have ran in to an error :

> Reference to type 'HtmlString' claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found

this is the part of code that is throwing this error
`@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))`

I have tried using both X.PagedList.Mvc and PagedList.Mvc - the only thing that changes is the type in the error, when I use X.PagedList.Mvc its

> 'HtmlString'

but when I use PagedList.Mvc its

> 'MvcHtmlString'

**What have I Tried**

I have tried to downgrading PagedList.Mvc to version 4.0.0 That changes nothing,
[This](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/microsoft-asp-net-mvc-security-update-ms14-059-broke-my-build/) - but cant do the second step which is this :

2. Manually update the reference to System.Web.MVC.dll (don’t use the one in the GAC).

   Try the Add Reference -> Assemblies -> Extensions dialog box.

I cant find a reference to System.Web.MVC.dll, I am not sure if I am looking in the right place

Any help would be great...

Comment: have you added @using PagedList.Mvc on the top of the view ?

Comment: yes, that didnt change a thing. :(